# Elasticsearch float/double field type precision

Tags: elasticsearch

I am experimenting with float/double fields in Elasticsearch (version 6.6.0). I have created this index:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "amount": {
            "type" : "float"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I added this entry:

```
PUT my_index/_doc/1
{
  "amount" : 1.0000000000111111111122222222223333333333
}
```

When I retrieve this document, I get the exact amount I have sent to Elastic:

```
GET my_index/_doc/1
...
    "_source": {
        "amount": 1.0000000000111111111122222222223333333333
    }
...
```

By checking the documentation, I would have expected the returning value to have less precision (less digits): [Elastic numeric data types documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/number.html)

> float - A single-precision 32-bit IEEE 754 floating point number,
>   restricted to finite values.

I wonder if Elasticsearch is keeping instead the value as a BigDecimal (or something similar), but I could not find any reference to that.

My question: is this documented somewhere? Am I missing something here?

Comment: There are two "kind" of stores. First - elastic stores all sent values in the same way as you sent it to elastic, and the second store is kind of internal index. The internal is used for some operations like aggregation, sorting and so on. But you get always the same values from elastic, as you sent before to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following [V-K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3519720/v-k)'s comment, I have experimented more and I observed that:

- Elasticsearch will return the original value sent to it (eg: 17.3), even if that value cannot be represented exactly in the type specified in the mapping (eg: integer);
- the value converted to the type specified in the mapping (eg: integer) will be used when evaluating search queries. For example, requesting all document for which integer field > 17.1 will NOT return a document for which the integer field was set to 17.3 (because internally Elasticsearch will see field == 17).